# количество загруженных документов c#

Tags: c#

В `dataGridView` загружаются документы Word.

Как отображать в поле `textBox` количество загруженных документов? Чтобы, в случае чего знать, какие документы были загружены, а какие нет

Comment: [DataGridView.RowCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спрашивать dataGridView, сколько в программу загружено документов - плохо. Вы можете спросить, сколько у него строк, но не документов. Лучше хранить коллекцию документов отдельно в программе, и работать с ней. А dataGridView используйте только для вывода информации пользователю.

Comment: ну количество строк у меня есть. Просто вдруг случится такое, что документы не все загрузились, а будут думать, что все, потом путаница начнется. И где искать те, которые не загрузились? Блин, сама вот не знаю как это сделать или вообще не делать. Или, например, если какой-то документ не загружается, то ошибка выпадала..

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov если строка в гриде обозначает *документ* то кол-во можно получить через кол-во строк. а если по сути то не достаточно информации: например класс описывающий документ. откуда/как узнать есть загруженный документ или нет

Comment: Яна добавьте информации в вопрос: что Вам надо сделать и что у Вас на текущий момент уже есть

Comment: @Bald Получить то можно, но очень не желательно. Чуть что - придется все переписывать. Логика программы и ее визуализация должны быть разделены.

Comment: @Bald ну и у меня есть программа, документы ворд загружаются в программу (Записываются в data.dat) и отображаются в таблице dataGridView, Необходимо что-то придумать такое, чтобы не оказаться в такой ситуации, что вдруг случайно не все доки загрузились, а какой именно не загрузился непонятно.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov я с вами полностью согласен. в идеале должен быть метод который возвращает *список документов* для отображения в гриде, метод который возвращает *кол-во документов без загруженного файла*

Comment: @Яна Сделайте класс-обертку под документ. Пусть у него будет поле - документ ворд. Пусть у него будет флаг - загружен да/нет. Пусть у него будет метод загрузить, который в конце устанавливает флаг в да. Если возникнет ошибка, вы будете знать, что этот документ не загружен. Еще пусть у вас в программе будет лист из этих классов-оберток. Когда создаете новый - добавляйте в этот лист. И только в конце добавления уже обновляйте ваш dataGridView.

Comment: Яна внесите исправления в вопрос в соответствии со своим [комментарием](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607858/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-c/607878#comment830190_607858)

Answer (score 2):

я бы наверно сделал как то так:

создал класс *Документ*:

```
public class Document
{    
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Path {get;set;}
    public bool HasAttachedFile {get;set;}
}
```

при прикреплении/загрузке файла в случае успеха ставил соответствующий флаг(*HasAttachedFile*) в `true`

```
public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
{
    //метод который будет возвращать список документов
}
```

в гриде должно быть поле показывающее есть *загруженный* файл или нет.

так же должен быть метод который будет показывать количество документов без загруженного файла

```
public int GetCountDocumentsWithoutAttachment()
{}
```